# Count rows with specific integer in a column

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have 6 columns, each with multiple rows.

I want to count the number of rows which have the integer 4 or 5 in the fifth column.

```
A1 jhfj jdhfjkhd kdkfjjh 5 jhsdjkfh
A2 ujhf jhdfhsd  dsfkks  4 jhsdfjhs
A3 jhfj jdhfjkhd kdkfjjh 5 jhsdjkfh
A4 jhfj jdhfjkhd kdkfjjh 5 jhsdjkfh
A5 ujhf jhdfhsd  dsfkks  4 jhsdfjhs
```

In the example presented, the result should be three for lines with a 5, and two for lines with a 4.

Comment: You mean that you want rows that do not contain 4 or 5 in the 5th column?

Comment: Skipping lines with 4 or 5 in the 5th column, what **do** you want to count? Number of lines, sum of the line lengths, sum of the 5 the column values, total number of columns?

Comment: @Zelda I assume the OP meant "No.", not "no".

Comment: @ChrisDown That could be, on reread I still can't figure out what is that "which has" refers to. I would assume someone using nr. in that case anyway.

Comment: @Zelda Standard British notation is "No." -- the OP's name (from the username) is "Taraka Ramji", a typically Indian name, and India tends towards using British abbreviation conventions. I'm just guessing here :-)

Comment: The "no" he meant numbers. no and No. are short for that word. It makes more sense to "count number columns" vs. "count no columns". Just a guess by me as well 8-). BTW where did the OP go? Glad we're all here waiting....

Comment: And will probably until a day when the OP returns (hoping that somebody might have answered) ...

Comment: I am sorry that i couldn't explain properly!! Updated!!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, now you could accept an answer and vote (once you have enough reputation).

Comment: Why did you accept that over what I wrote? My A which was the first one here showed the exact same command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only `awk`:

```
awk '
  $5==4{c4++};
  $5==5{c5++};
  END{
    print "Fours: "c4;
    print "Fives: "c5;
  }' your_file
```

or `perl`:

```
perl -lane '
  $count{$F[4]}++;
  END{
    print "Fours: $count{4}";
    print "Fives: $count{5}"
  }' your_file
```

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the gross counts for rows with a 4 and rows with a 5 in the 5th column.

```
$ awk '{print $5}' somefile | sort | uniq -c
      2 4
      3 5
```

The counts the first digit in the output, the 2nd column is which number it corresponds to from the 5th column.

Comment: Note to the OP: this assumes all rows have either a 4 or a 5 in the fifth column; otherwise, it will print counts for other values in the fifth column as well.

Answer (score 0):

Following execution will lead you to your required output.

> 1)    awk '{print $5}' 4.txt | grep -c 4
>
> 2) awk '{print $5}' 4.txt | grep -c 5
>
> 3) awk '{print $5}' 4.txt | sort | uniq -c

Explanation:

-c option will count the no. of pattern matched in all above cases

Answer (score -1):

```
cat file | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$6}'
```

output is:

```
A1 jhfj jdhfjkhd kdkfjjh jhsdjkfh
A2 ujhf jhdfhsd dsfkks jhsdfjhs
A3 jhfj jdhfjkhd kdkfjjh jhsdjkfh
A4 jhfj jdhfjkhd kdkfjjh jhsdjkfh
A5 ujhf jhdfhsd dsfkks jhsdfjhs
```

there is no 5 and 4 in the lines in th 5th column. From your post I hope that you requested like this.

Comment: So what it is that is being counted (as requested by the OP)?

Comment: `awk` takes the filename as an argument: no need for UUOC...