# Counting the number of columns below a value for each row

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I need to count the number of columns that have a value < 5 by row. My data looks like this:

```
1.2 8.9  4.5  2.8 
4.9 10.1 15.3 1.1 
2.1 4.3  3.9  3.3 
.
.
```

So the desired output is like this:

```
3
2
4
```

Comment: You tagged this with [tag:awk]. Have you made any attempt to solve it with `awk`? What part of the solution are you stuck at?

Comment: I saw similar problems solved with awk like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115001/count-rows-with-specific-integer-in-a-column), so I supposed it might be good to tag it there, but any command that can solve the issue is good. I know how to count the number of rows within a column that are below or above certain value combining 'awk' and 'wc', but I do not know how to count columns per row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of fields per record (whitespace-delimited columns per row, by default) is `NF`.  You may loop over all the fields in a record with `for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)`.  The data in field `i` would be available in `$i` inside the loop.  For example:

```
awk '{ count = 0; for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i < 5) ++count; print count }'
```

or, writing it out more verbosely,

```
awk '
    {
        count = 0

        for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
            if ($i < 5)
                ++count

        print count
    }'
```

Since the bodies of the `if` and `for` statements are only one single statement, no extra wrapping in `{ ... }` is needed (as in the C programming language, but unlike in Perl).  The `;` at the end of lines are not needed unless for separating one statement from another on the same line (compare the use of `;` in the two equivalent code snippets above, for example).

Answer (score 2):

An alternate, using Perl:

```
perl -alpe '$_ = grep { $_ < 5 } @F' file
```

Scalar assignment of the grep result turns it into a count of matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

Run the input thru `tr` and turn all dashes to underscores, which is used to recognize a negative number by `dc`:

```
$ tr \- _ < inp.txt |
  dc -e '
  [q]sq
  [lN1+sN]sa
  [5>az0<b]sb
  [?z0=q0sNlbxlNpcz0=c]sc
  lcx
 '
```

Comment: The `dc` bit may need further explanation.